# better way of handle clojure exceptions and why my exception is not captured inside go block

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to found a better way of handle exceptions in clojure, I'm using https://github.com/alaisi/postgres.async which thrown an exeption when fail, but I would prefer return false (because I'm using a validator) or even better something like a Either monad (or something more simple like this http://adambard.com/blog/acceptable-error-handling-in-clojure/ )

1) I'm trying to catch the exception and if exist return false, but the code doesnt works (doesnt return false and thrown the exception).

```
(try
      (dosql [tx (<begin! db)
                 ucount (<execute! tx ["UPDATE groups SET garticlescounter=garticlescounter + 1 WHERE gid=$1"
                                       groupid])
                 uartc (<execute! tx ["UPDATE subtopics SET starticlescount=starticlescount + 1 WHERE stid=$1"
                                      sid])
                 uartins (<insert! tx
                                   {:table "articles"}
                                   {:aurl url :atitle title :asuttopicid sid :acommentcount 0 :alikescount 0 :auid uid})
                 ok? (<commit! tx)]
                ok?)
      (catch Exception _ false))
```

2)would be possible wrap in a way where if works return ok?  and if doesnt works return false, or maybe [ok? nil] and [nil error] maybe a macro?

----thanks to swinn I did this

```
;must receive an optional parameter for error response or 
; build a [nil ok] response but just know this works for me...
(defmacro async-try-block! [block]
  `(let [chn# (!/chan 1)]
     (!/go
       (let [response# (try
                        ~block
                        (catch Throwable e#))]
         (if (instance? Throwable response#) (!/put! chn# false) (!/put! chn# response#))))
     chn#))

(async-try-block!
    (dosql [tx (<begin! db)
            ucount (<execute! tx ["UPDATE groups SET garticlescounter=garticlescounter + 1 WHERE gid=$1"
                                  groupid])
            uartc (<execute! tx ["UPDATE subtopics SET starticlescount=starticlescount + 1 WHERE stid=$1"
                                 sid])
            uartins (<insert! tx
                              {:table "articles"}
                              {:aurl url :atitle title :asuttopicid sid :acommentcount 0 :alikescount 0 :auid uid})
            ok? (<commit! tx)]
           ok?))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the postgres.async library, but`Exception` is not the root of all Exceptions in the JVM, `Throwable` is.

Changing your catch to `Throwable` would be the first change I would suggest, but it seems that `(<execute! ...)` actually catches the exception for you and returns it, so you need to check the return value using `(instance? Throwable)`

Comment: thanks, I did a small macro for handle this..the error was  use Exception instead of Throwable